# Creating a style inherited from 2 themes

Tags: android

I would like to create a style from both `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">` and   `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` Is there a away to for example inherited from 2 themes, or there a better way to use 2 theme at the same time.

Thanks.

Comment: No, you can't inherit from two themes. Why not just use Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog?

Comment: @alanv Thanks... correct me if I'm wrong, this will require android 3.0 as minimum, but I would like to support Android 2.3